# Failing SSL verification for some clients, tracing the missing cert(s)

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

We have a few SSL webservers that work perfectly fine for the vast majority of clients, however a small minority fail to validate the SSL certificate chain. In at least some of the failing cases a proxy server is involved, but we at least do not use client certs.

The short version of what I'm hoping for is to find some tool (or tools) to allow us to trace not just what certs are received from the server (openssl s_client can do that), but also what certs are available locally, where they are loaded from, and generally what the chains look like or if there are multiple valid paths.

---

For more specific context of our scenario and why we need better investigative tooling:

- This is not a simple pass or fail for a given machine.
- We have multiple endpoints with different but similar certs (same root CA, i.e. all Amazon, but differing intermediates).
- Some apps e.g. Chrome, PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest are able to validate the problem endpoints successfully, while others can't (notably for us our Java application is failing).
- Chrome passing isn't an especially valuable indication as it has it's own internal cert store now.
- Our Java app doesn't fail for everything so it isn't as simple as just the proxy cert not being made available to Java (the proxy cert is specifically loaded in and trusted which fixes at least some cases).
- We have verified with other applications, Chrome and Invoke-WebRequest being the most notable.
- We have verified each route's cert chain is valid and as expected on working machines.
- We have confirmed our custom app can load all relevant accessible CA
  cert stores.
- We are in the process of confirming the contents of less accessible CA stores.
- We are attempting to verify the cert chain as seen by the problematic clients.

Comment: (1) What does the so-called `clients` mean? (2)  Is it a Java application or a Browser? (3) tru command like `curl -iv  https://www.google.com`

Comment: (1&2) When I wrote the post I was thinking of it in terms of an entire machine, but actually it is probably more relevant to say it's our Java application. (3) It appears Curl will only print the leaf SSL cert, but I'm pretty sure our server is sending the intermediates too. Openssl s_client still seems better, but also both are only dealing with the server certs.

Comment: If the Client is a Java application, it may also be necessary to check the `.keystore` of the JDK or JRE underlying the Java application.